# channelReadComplete called before channelRead

Tags: java, netty

Does anyone know why channelReadComplete gets called before channelRead in some situations?  I have a server that is pretty dumb right now that another netty server connects to.  The first initializer does this:

```
    final EventExecutorGroup taskGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(50);

    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ctx.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast(taskGroup, "ServerHandler", new ServerHandler());
```

And then in ServerHandler

```
public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        System.out.println("channelRead");

//        ctx.write(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("channelReadComplete");
//        ctx.flush();
    }
```

I consistently get channelReadComplete before channelRead when the first netty server connects to the second netty server.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: You use a DefaultEventExecutorGroup with 50 threads in parallel. What it means "before" in this specific case ? Can you confirm this happens on before on the same thread ?